# XML Task error message hexadecimal invalid character

Tags: xml, ssis, task

I am developing a SSIS package to add data from an XML file to an existing SQL Server table.  I have completed several similar projects, but on this XML file I am getting the error from the Data Flow tab between the XML Task and Data Flow Task:

```
Error: 0xC002F304 at XML Task, XML Task: An error occurred with the following error message: 
"'', hexadecimal value 0x15, is an invalid character. Line 28, position 54.".
Error: 0xC002928F at XML Task, XML Task: Property "New Source" has no source Xml text; 
Xml Text is either invalid, null or empty string.
Task failed: XML Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at zSTU_TS_Element: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "zStu_TS_Element.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

This is the line it is referring to from my XML file:

```
<z:row c0='12' c1='80' c2='2006-04-17' c3='539' c4='1M2083N4N5N6N75800901110 11 '/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not wrong. The character ‘U+0015 Negative Acknowledge’ (0x15, ASCII 21) is a control code which cannot be put in an XML 1.0 file. The XML file you have is not well-formed (and hence not really an XML file); try to open it in any other XML reader (eg. IE) and you should get the same error.

You'll need to hack that character out of the file using a text editor, and have a look at whatever broken source produced it.

(Unfortunately we can't see that character posted here, as it's a typically-invisible control code which StackOverflow filters out anyway. A good text editor should, however, be able to display some sort of marker that it's there. The column number in the error suggests it is at the start of the `c4` attribute value, though this isn't necessarily reliable.)

Comment: THanks!  I just researched myself and u r correct.  I researched a little on XML 2.0 but it doesn't seem to support this character either.  Can u confirm this?

Comment: XML 1.1 allows the character, but only encoded as a character reference, eg. `&#21;`. There's very little purpose in doing this. XML 2.0 doesn't exist at the moment, it's only ideas being kicked about for removing XML's legacy cruft.